# Creating a If statement to post a themify image next to a post title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a simple blog and I'm using paperclip to be able to add images to a Post. I installed the 'themify-icons-rails' gem and what I want to do is automatically add a picture icon next to the title of a post when the post has a image that's been uploaded, to show that the post has a image. I'm guessing I would need a If statement somewhere but I'm fairly new to rails and I'm not sure where to put it.

`<h2 class="ti-gallery"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>` this adds the "Ti-gallery" icon to every post.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you before hand. Oh and one more questions, Is rails Video friendly? i can't seem to find any tutorials on uploading videos to a rails app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if there is image posted, by checking the return data as you render it in page, like:

I assume you have the following field names under

**Posts  Table** (image_file_name, image_content_type, image_file_size),

since you are using Paperclip, if yes? Then you have **codes in Post Model** for image upload.

My **answer** should be in ***index.html.erb*** as your

**Posts controller** render like **@posts**.

Finally you can do inside interation, like :

**Key**: post.image returns application root path as generated by paperclip.

**Example**: "/images/posts/1/original/sample.jpg"

```
<% unless post.image.nil? %>
   // render image here
<% else %>
  // render default image
  <span class="ti-image"></span>
<% end %>
```

Please modify the code, as what you need.

**Note**, that you can use if statement instead of unless. No problem with that.

The **unless statement** checks if the image is present or not nil.

**Additional Info**:

https://github.com/hpoydar/themify-icons-rails

http://themify.me/themify-icons

Comment: Thanks aldrien.h , Excuse my ignorance, as I am new to rails, where would i put that, in my Post controller or my Index.html.erb file?     and How would I write the syntax. I seem to get a nameerror for "<% unless image_file_name.nil? %>" My Index.html.erb is: <% @posts.each do |post| %>
<div class="post_wrapper">
<h6><p class="date"><%= post.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></p></h6>
<h2 class="ti-gallery"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>

</div>

<% end %>

Comment: Hi @PrideCoding, I will update the answer for further explanations.

Comment: Thanks Adrien, I created a Gist, so you can check out what I did, it's still not working, here's the link to the Gist https://gist.github.com/Elyseemontissol/9887a16a6e9412444540

Comment: Hi @PrideCoding, try to adjust your code in index.html.erb. <% unless post.image.nil? %> 
<span class="ti-gallery"><%= link_to post.title, post %></span>
<% else %>     
<h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
<% end %>

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!!!, i figured it out, removing the nil? actually worked. Question How friendly is rails with videos, I also want to upload videos. but can't seem to find any tutorials on doing that.

Comment: Welcome, consider to use if statement if you're confuse using "unless". please mark this answer as the Answer to your question if this solved your problem :)

Comment: Sure, Oh and that's something else i did, I used IF instead of UNLESS

Comment: Hi @PrideCoding, please check this answer, so your question will be mark as solved. Thank you!